# Select specific all key paths and values for a specific key name in deeply nested JSON

Tags: text-processing, json, jq

I have a very large JSON schema that is semi structured, the nested unit structures are tagged by a key: "ObjectType" to indicate some meaningful information.

I am trying to use jq to select paths of all these ObjectType(s) and their values.

Sample part of json is :

```
{
    "ObjectType": "ClassZ",
    "LastModifiedBy": "janeroe",
    "Name": "Anonymous",
    "ArrayProps": [],
    "Logistics": [
      {
        "ObjectType": "ClassA",
        "Source": "Vendor",
        "UUID": "x868-dhibye9-7678-12",
        "EffectiveDate": "2020-01-01",
        "Active": true,
        "Preferred": 0
      }
    ],
    "IsVirtual": true,
    "Convention": 3,
    "CruiseParams": [
      {
        "ObjectType": "ClassB",
        "Destinaton": "Atlantis",
        "Value": "3"
      }
    ],
    "InvolvedParties": [],
    "PartyEvents": [
      {
        "ObjectType": "ClassC",
        "CreatedDate": "2020-01-01",
        "CreatedBy": "johndoe"
      }
    ],
    "FunFactors": [
      {
        "ObjectType": "ClassD",
        "Level": 1
      }
    ]
  }
```

Trying to output something similar or close to :

```
"ObjectType":                "ClassZ"
"Logistics/0/ObjectType":    "ClassA"
"CruiseParams/0/ObjectType": "ClassB"
"PartyEvents/0/ObjectType":  "ClassC"
"FunFactors/0/ObjectType":   "ClassD"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best I can come up with, based on [How to get the index path of found values using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34166237)

```
$ jq -rc 'paths as $p | select($p[-1] == "ObjectType") | "\($p|@csv): \"\(getpath($p))\""' sample.json
"ObjectType": "ClassZ"
"Logistics",0,"ObjectType": "ClassA"
"CruiseParams",0,"ObjectType": "ClassB"
"PartyEvents",0,"ObjectType": "ClassC"
"FunFactors",0,"ObjectType": "ClassD"
```

The quoting and delimiting is not exactly what you asked for - using your suggested `map(tostring)| join(“/“)` from comments it becomes

```
$ jq -rc 'paths as $p | select($p[-1] == "ObjectType") | "\"\($p|map(tostring)|join("/"))\": \"\(getpath($p))\""' sample.json
"ObjectType": "ClassZ"
"Logistics/0/ObjectType": "ClassA"
"CruiseParams/0/ObjectType": "ClassB"
"PartyEvents/0/ObjectType": "ClassC"
"FunFactors/0/ObjectType": "ClassD"
```

Comment: I can get all the paths path(..)|map(tostring)| join(“/“) , and grep ObjectType then mix and match. Problem is I don’t know the entire json, so I cannot use column names. Only thing I know is there will be ObjectType inside all or most of the nested structure. Was trying to find a functional way instead of grep.

Comment: @user221826 I have added your suggested `map(tostring)| join(“/“)` formating. I don't understand what you mean by "cannot use column names"

Comment: The answer is good. I should have edited the question instead of comments. I meant the answer should work for any generic schema

Comment: @user221826 ah, gotcha I see what you mean now